# twitter bootstrap not fit the page in Firefox

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter bootstrap following is the markup

```
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">blah</div>

 <div class="row-fluid"> 
   <div class="span3">column1</div>
   <div class="span7">column2</div>
   <div class="span2">column3<div>
 </div>
</body>
```

it works fine in IE9 but it not fit in one row in firefox, I mean column2 and 3 are under column1, even if I decrease width of the columns (for example by changing span7 to 6). thanks for your advice

Comment: are you using bootstap-responsive.css? it works fine for me in firefox http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/5gagF/

Comment: Yes I use bootsratp-responsive.css
actually the markup is more than what I have written but it follows same pattern. If I remvoe style=direction:rtl; from my div class="row-fluit" it does not work on IE niether.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the piece of code above.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<div class="span2">column3</div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="span2">column3<div>
```

Comment: I am sorry about my mistake, I wrote wrong. the markup is what you have written but still same error,